# Выбор книги по C#

Tags: c#, книги

Недавно появились на полках магазинах новые издания книг по C#. Хотелось обсудить какая книга лучше всего подходит для человека, который не имел дело с программирование и хочет начать с свое знакомство с C#. Думаю смысл обсуждения есть потому, что люди которые хотят заниматься C# и не имею опыта в программирование имеет смысл начинать изучение с 2010 студии и 4 версии платформы .NET. Вот какие бы книги я бы хотел обсудить

1. Грин Д., Стиллмен Э. Изучаем C#. 2-е изд. Серия: Head First O'Reilly
   Карли Уотсон, Кристиан Нейгел, Якоб Хаммер Педерсен, Джон Д. Рид, Морган Скиннер Visual
2. C# 2010. Полный курс
3. C# 4.0: полное руководство. Герберт Шилдт

Я отдаю предпочтения первым двум книгам потому, что после каждой главы в них имеются упражнения. Хочу услышать ваши мнения на счет данных книг.

Comment: Head First C# в этом списке наиболее годная, я нигде ещё не встречал настолько грамотного и доходчивого изложения.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2):

На `stackoverflow.com` отчаянно советуют [**Head First C#.**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514822.do)

Answer (score 1):

Читал 1 и не до конца 3. По формату изложения, больше нравится 1. Мне кажется книга подойдёт не только новичкам, но и людям которые уже разбираются в языке и которые хотят структурировать все знания в голове.

Answer (score 0):

C# 4.0: полное руководство. Герберт Шилдт
По мне так книга в самый раз для новичков, интересное описание, постоянные упражнения. Книга большая, но там можно найти всё что душе угодно, советую! ))))

Comment: А что смешного? Каждый нормальный программер должен читать по-английски. Я сам несколько технологий изучал по английским книгам.

Comment: где вы в Шилдте нашли упражнения?

Answer (score 0):

Первая книга из списка и есть  Head First C# в переводе
для себя выбрал сочетание - первой, на английском, и третьей на русском. хед фирст дает упражнения, а у шилдта все структурировано и если что то не понял в первой книге то по шилдту уточняешь